# Usage of preposition

Tags: prepositions

What is correct?
...I always pointed to everything that was three, 
referring **to** me and my parents.

or

referring me and my parents.

Is it correct to state 'referring to my parents and me'?

Answer (score 1):

This is one case where it *is* correct to use **myself** rather than **me** - "Referring to my parents and myself"

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is correct, although the verb *refer* doesn't necessarily go with the prepsotion *to*. If you refer **to** an object, then you mean that you use this object as a source of information or other utility. When you refer a person to some object, so without the prepositon, it means that you recommend that object to them loosely speaking. So for example you can refer your friend to a book or to a specialist, meaning that they should read the book or visit the specialist.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not correct. _Refer to_ can perfectly well mean _allude to_.

Comment: "Refer to" and "Refer someone to"; are they different?